# Why am i receiving this error when setting up a new angular project: ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have updated cli, npm, and node js and i'm still getting the following message:

ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
    at resolveAlias (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36513:37)
    at checkAliasSymbol (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64502:26)
    at checkImportBinding (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64534:13)
    at checkImportDeclaration (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64552:29)
    at checkSourceElementWorker (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64961:28)
    at checkSourceElement (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64800:17)
    at Object.forEach (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:317:30)
    at checkSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65123:20)
    at checkSourceFile (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65091:13)
    at getDiagnosticsWorker (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65179:17)
    at Object.getDiagnostics (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65165:24)
    at C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98703:85
    at runWithCancellationToken (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98665:24)
    at getBindAndCheckDiagnosticsForFileNoCache (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98691:20)
    at getAndCacheDiagnostics (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98956:26)
    at getBindAndCheckDiagnosticsForFile (C:\Users\jeffc\OneDrive\Desktop\angular\my-first-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98688:20)